# Apply map and filter simultaneously in SWI prolog?

Tags: dictionary, filter, prolog

I have the following predicate:

```
 checkMachinePenaltiesRange(MachinePenaltiesArray):-
                         maplist(atom_chars , MachinePenaltiesArray, ListOfLists),
                         writeln(ListOfLists),
                         maplist( exclude(isSpace,X,NoSpacesArray) ,ListOfLists,ListOfLists1),
                         writeln(ListOfLists1).

% Helper function for exclude predicate
isSpace(X):- X == '',!.
```

And I apply it in the following way:

```
checkMachinePenaltiesRange([1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, 1.3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1])
```

Which first maps this list to list-of lists like so:

`[[1,,1,,1,,1,,1,,1,,1,,1,], [1,,2,,3,,4,,5,,6,,7,,8], [1.3,,1,,1,,1,,1,,1,,1,,1]]`

And then I would like to remove all spaces so the result is:

`[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [1.3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]`

However the `exclude` (filter predicate) doesn't want to work with `maplist` together to achieve the result I want. How could those two be combined?

Comment: Try replacing `exclude(isSpace,X,NoSpacesArray)` with `exclude(isSpace)`. Also, you can define the `isSpace/1` predicate simply as `isSpace(' ').`. Instead of `writeln/1` use `writeq/1`+ `nl/0` to make output clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time, findall/3 was *the* list processing of choice, and when you have just *one* list with elements computed from *one* input, it's easier than maplist/3, since you can 'inline' the goal and it also acts naturally as filter. You just need member/2 to scan the input and the pattern (first argument) will fill the result. For instance

```
isSpace(' '). % note: no cut needed, and test 'pushed' in the head

checkMachinePenaltiesRange(MachinePenaltiesArray, ListOfLists1):-
    findall(List, (member(I,MachinePenaltiesArray),
                atom_chars(I,Cs),
                findall(C,(member(C,Cs),\+isSpace(C)),List)
               ),ListOfLists1).

checkMachinePenaltiesRange_OP(MachinePenaltiesArray,ListOfLists1):-
    maplist(atom_chars,MachinePenaltiesArray,ListOfLists),
    maplist(exclude(isSpace),ListOfLists,ListOfLists1).
```

You can see in checkMachinePenaltiesRange_OP/2 your example code cleaned up, and compare the differences. But the output will not be that useful. Discarding spaces from a space separated text is rarely the clever thing to do. When you have floats (like `1.3`) in your list would need to recover them... a real pain. If you have control on the spacing, consider instead

```
?- atomic_list_concat(L,' ','1.3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1').
L = ['1.3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'].
```